# Bit flags operation

Tags: byte, bitwise-operators, bit, flags, bitwise-and

I am going through some format spec and I am encountering the following:

> if (flags & 1) { 
> ...
> }

Now, according to the same documentation **flags** is:

[image]

so the flags is 3 bytes. The operation **flags & 1** I suppose is doing a bitwise operation between the flags and ..? 1 expressed in a 24 bit long manner? could someone explain me a bit more? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec should list the available flags and you can then just use the individual bits to toggle them on/off.

For instance the Python [ssl](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html) module has multiple [constants](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#constants) that we can use to change some options (flags).

Let's see if **TLS version 1.0** option is enabled:

```
>>> import ssl
>>> ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
>>> bin(ctx.options)
'0b10000010010100100000000001010100'
>>> int(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
3
>>> bin(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
'0b11'
>>> bool(ctx.options & ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
False
```

We can see that the first two bits (3 in decimal) are not set and therefore this option is not enabled so let's enable it:

```
>>> ctx.options |= ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
>>> bin(ctx.options)
'0b10000010010100100000000001010111'
>>> bool(ctx.options & ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
True
```

I guess this has a similar purpose in your case.

Comment: kind of similar but make me understand how it works! thanks a lot :)